# analysis proof about convergence. What is limit definition?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm stuck on Question 1. Obviously since A_n goes to zero, b_n/a_n will go to zero but how do I prove it? I don't know what they mean by LIMIT DEFINITION. Could you give me hints?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the definition of limit?

Comment: Look in the book/lecture notes. Some time before, the limit of a sequence will have been defined.

Comment: It should read something like:  "For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that ..."

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is:

A sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is said to converge to a limit $l \in \mathbb{R}$ if, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq N$, we have $|a_n - l | < \epsilon$.

We then say that $l$ is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, or write $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = l$$

It might help to supply some intuition: the $N$ means that on and after the $N$th term of the sequence, the value of that term is then arbitrarily close to the limit.

Comment: I think it would be useful to add the definition for the case where $\lim a_n= \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For part a) think about how epsilon relates to the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty $ and  $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$ in order to get $\frac{b_n}{a_n}<\epsilon$.

For b this deals with the divergence criteria for limits. It should read

> For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a natural number $N(\alpha)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N(\alpha)$ then $x_n>\alpha$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This implies that the $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =\infty$.

Part b) you can use that fact that since  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$. there exists a natural number $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $a_n>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Similarly there exists a natural number $N'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N'$ then $b_n>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore if we let $m=max\{N,N'\}$ such that if $n\geq m$ we have $a_n+b_n>\epsilon$. Thus by the divergence criteria we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n+b_n=\infty$
And this works because we also at the same time have taken care of all the negative numbers as well since $\epsilon>0$.